# What Comes Next?

Tags: number-sequence

Which number comes next in the sequence?

2, 7, 19, 47, 83, ___

---

Please remember to explain your reasoning and put your answer and reasoning behind spoilers. (Do >! and then your text to put one)

Comment: http://www.leastcommonmultiple.net/lcm-of-14-19-47-and-83/

Comment: Hmm... Yeah... What's Your Point?

Comment: No point, just an observation.

Comment: Oh, well okay then

Comment: They're all primes, that's what you're trying to say, perhaps

Comment: @leoll2 Well yes good observation but does that have anything to do with the answer? Maybe or maybe not.

Comment: They do all fit the form of $-\frac{17}{24}x^4 + \frac{103}{12}x^3  - \frac{727}{24}x^2 + \frac{557}{12}x - 22$, I believe. Logically, the next number would then be 102.

Comment: Wow that's, um okay then. post an answer in the answers and you may be right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a sequence extracted from the series of prime numbers. The next number could be:

> **139** which is the $34^{th}$ prime number.
>
> The sequence to select prime numbers is $n^2-floor((n-1)/2)$
>
>  [image: Sequence]

Comment: It's surprisingly close to the prime numbers at Fibonacci indices - 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34

Comment: @mdc32 - Yes, that would also work by using an adjustment function of -2,-1, 0,+2,+2 which would be a little more complex.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the commas are superfluous; the numbers could relate to

> This marker on the Neanderthal genome; http://neandertal.ensemblgenomes.org/Homo_sapiens/Location/Marker?r=16:26994784-27194783. The next number would therefore be 16.

Comment: Sorry, that's not it, but I will upvote for the effort.

Answer (score 5):

The Next Number's will be:

> 139,199

The Reason is:

> The Sequence is following +1, +3,+1,+3,......

The Prime number sequence is 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199,..

The logic is as following:

> 2 *after 2 prime numbers, it is* 7
>  7 *after 3=>(2+**1**) prime numbers, it is* 19
>  19 *after 6=>(3+**3**) prime numbers, it is* 47
>  47 *after 7=>(6+**1**) prime numbers, it is* 83
>  83 *after 10=>(7+**3**) prime numbers, it is* 139 and so on...

Finally:

> 2,7,19,47,83,139